# DDR Trace Length Inside Package from Simulation Model

Tags: pcb-design, layout, trace, ddr, length-matching

The DDR4 in question is a [Micron MT40A512M16JY](https://www.micron.com/parts/dram/ddr4-sdram/mt40a512m16jy-083e-ait). From the vendor site, you can get the datasheets, specs, sim models. I assume from the sim models you should be able to see the trace length of each signal pin inside the package. But I can't figure out how to interpret the files. Anybody knows how to read those sim models manually? If it is not in the sim models, where to find out those lengths?

I know that I do not have the skill to run the sim model with HiSpice tool. The purpose of this question is to compute trace length alignment in layout. So I just need a way to know the length of each signal.

Comment: This linked question (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/60789/is-there-a-pcb-layout-related-reasoning-behind-ddr-memory-package-and-footprint) shows some hints but still no clear answer to my original question. Another related question (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/337223/ddr2-4-training-and-length-matching) does too.

Answer (score 2):

You will be able to access this data with *Visual IBIS Editor*. With this software you will be able to get the information you need, it is able to open the ***.ibs*** files.

[Download Visual IBIS Editor](https://www.mentor.com/pcb/downloads/visual_ibis_editor/visual_ibis_editor_dl_ok?type=offer&resourceID=79039ed3-7865-44ff-ac59-2d629c2d97f7&subID=AD5E715E-C3D5-4FC2-A1849541EE67C51F%3Adirect%3Aself)

Comment: Hi, Eduardo, I installed the IBIS editor and opened the ibis files. It seems the trace length could not be found. Do you see it?

Comment: I still have not figured out how to get the trace lengths from the model or another source.